# Formula to increase x by y z times

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

What is the formula to increase x by y  z times?

For example the number 4 I want to increase by 4 50 times.  I added it out (4+8+12+16+20+24 etc....to 204) and got the right answer 5304 but what is the algebraic formula to get it vs adding them out?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This is an [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).  The sum is $\dfrac{51(4+204)}2$

Comment: This kind of question has been asked and answered many times on this site. Please use the search engine.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the formula to increase $x$ by $y$, $z$ times?

According to your e.g. you want to find,
$$S:{=x+(x+y)+(x+2y)+...+(x+zy)\\=(z+1)x+y(1+2+3+...+z)\\
=(z+1)x+y\cdot\frac{z(z+1)}{2}\quad(\text{Sum of first $z$ integers.})\\=(z+1)\left(x+\frac{yz}2\right)}$$

Now, put $x=4,y=4,z=50$ and check it,
$$(50+1)\cdot\left(4+\frac{4\times50}{2}\right)=5304$$